# Automatically importing products into Woocommerce

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to find a way to automatically import products into Woocommerce. I was wondering if someone had any experience with this, whether using a CSV or directly writing to the database.

Comment: have you tried anything? In what format you have data for importing?

Comment: Hi Tom. My current data set is in a SQL server database. I have looked at exporting the data into a CSV and using an existing plugin to import the data. The database structure for storing additional attributes seems a bit confusing to me, and so I resorted to doing this. Still not automated, though a couple of clicks seems to do the job for now.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

1. The Easy Way:

You can easily import CSV files into WooCommerce using the CSV Import Extension:
http://www.woothemes.com/extension/product-csv-import-suite/

Or you can use the more flexible WP All In One Import: http://www.wpallimport.com/woocommerce-product-import/

Automating product import from CSV is possible with this [WooCommerce plugin](https://woocommerce.com/products/import-export-suite-for-woocommerce/)

There is also a free solution via this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/

2. The Hard Way:

Woocommerce Products are regular WordPress posts, with a custom post type of `product`. This means that each product is stored in the `wp_posts` table (or replace `wp` with your table prefix). There are many post_type values here. The ones for WordPress have a `post_type="product"`

All additional product info is stored in the table `wp_postmeta` and connected by the `post_id` column to the `wp_posts` table. There are many meta key/values used, but the most common ones for WooCommerce are fairly intuitive, such as: _visibiilty, _price, _sku, _stock, _length, _width, _height, etc...

I suggest you manually input several products into the WP Admin and then study the data in the tables to make sure you have all the data you need... then you can write your own custom import suite.

Doing it yourself probably will not work as well as some of the pre-made solutions which provide you with good error checking of the input data, and additional fields and preprocessing functions.

Comment: Hi ethanpil. Thanks for your this useful thoughts. I have already bought the CSV import plugins. I was in a hurry when I posted this and so I went ahead and bought the plugin. While using it I realised that the plugin would do most of the job as long as the structure of my data remains the same (which it does in 9/10 cases). So for the time being I can make do with the plugin, as I am still prototyping this project. Mean time I studied the DB a bit and it looked a bit messy. Will take another look at it based on your comments. Thanks much again.

Comment: @ethanpil to upload multiple products from myphpadmin database. since i am new to queries, can you help me with one for uploading simple products with these details "Product Title, Description, sku, Price and sale price, upsel and cross sell products, attributes and image".. i have to upload around 4000 products..so i am looking for a way to upload them all using Database..requesting your guidance..

Comment: The FREE plugin you recommend is not available for download. Reason cited: security issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have CSV full of WooCommerce simple Products , you can import all those along with images from URL in one click with [this free plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/)

Answer (score 1):

The **WordPress Importer** will import the following content from a WordPress export file:

- Posts, pages and other custom post types
- Comments
- Products
- Custom fields and post meta
- Categories, tags and terms from custom taxonomies
- Authors

You can use **[WordPress Importer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/)** plugin for import products into Woocommerce.

- **Installation of the Plugin**-

  1. Visit Tools -> Import in the WordPress dashboard
  2. Click on the WordPress link in the list of importers
  3. Click "Install Now"
  4. Finally click "Activate Plugin & Run Importer"
- **Usage of the Plugin**-

  **Step 1 :**  Go to the Tools -> Import screen

  **Step 2 :** Click on WordPress.

  **Step 3 :** Select Input File from a computer.

  **Step 4:** Click on Import

> **Video Tutorial**- The video tutorial on the following page might also be a good resource for import products -
>
> [How to import dummy .xml data in wordpress](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kUZhiTDdglg)